# Create buy/sell signal based on open of the next day

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading

For instance, I buy when close>sma(close,50) and sell when close<sma(close,50). Buy and sell action are all happening at the open of next day. But if the open of next day is lower than sma(close,50), I don't want to buy and if the open of next day is higher than sma(close,50), I don't want to sell cuz those are more like a shakeout. What should I do to build this strategy?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Any problem with my question? Thanks.

Comment: This isn't an indicator-writing service. It's a forum where Pine coders help each other resolve coding challenges. A generous coder from here may volunteer to write your indicator, but don't hold your breath. If you are interested in learning Pine, this is the best place to start: [pinecoders.com](https://www.pinecoders.com/) If you need to hire someone to help you, we maintain a list of [Trusted Pine Programmers for Hire](https://www.pinecoders.com/resources/#trusted-pine-programmers-for-hire).

Comment: @BjornMistiaen LOL, I ask how to build it. I don't ask someone to write it for me.

Comment: You should make an attempt at writing a script that does what you want. If there's a problem with that script, then you can post it here, and the community will help you solve it.